# getting the string value before dot in string through java

Tags: java, string

I have a string named extractDb values can be

```
GDSHKG.db
GDSMNH.db
GDSTKY.db
GDSLDN.db
```

now i want to remove the .extension partof it

that is i want to see the result as

```
GDSHKG
GDSMNH
GDSTKY
GDSLDN
```

please advise how to achieve this in java

Comment: Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941272/how-do-i-trim-a-file-extension-from-a-string-in-java); or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541550/remove-the-extension-of-a-file).

Comment: Your task looks like a simple search in string. Have a look into the developer's reference.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `substring` like this:

```
    String myString = "GDSHKG.db";
    String newString = myString.substring(0, myString.indexOf("."));
     System.out.print(newString);
```

Output:

```
  GDSHKG
```