# How to unzip file with sub-directories in android?

Tags: java, android, io, unzip

When i was unzip file.it's make file name like Movies\Hollywood\spider-Man.
Actually **Movies** is a Folder,**Hollywood** is a Folder in Movies and **spider-Man** is file in Hollywood.

Comment: Please paste the code

Comment: <pre><code>   public static void unzip(String Filepath,String DestinationFolderPath){

        try {
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(Filepath);
            zipFile.extractAll(DestinationFolderPath);
        } catch (ZipException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Comment: provide some code, it would be hard to tell without looking into code. Pleaes make sure that the specified entry was file (and NOT directory) when zip was created.

Comment: i'm using zip4j library for unzip. i get all file but like as that a write in description of question.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40125872/6478047 answer

Answer (score 3):

If *Movies\Hollywood\spider-Man* is a file while creating the zip it should be extracted as file, no matters whether it has extension or not (like *.mp4, *.flv)

You can rely on java APIs under namespace java.util.zip, the documentation link is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/package-summary.html)

Written some code which extracts only zip files, it should extract the file entry as file (no gzip, rar is supported).

```
private boolean extractFolder(File destination, File zipFile) throws ZipException, IOException
{
    int BUFFER = 8192;
    File file = zipFile;
    //This can throw ZipException if file is not valid zip archive
    ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(file);
    String newPath = destination.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + FilenameUtils.removeExtension(zipFile.getName());
    //Create destination directory
    new File(newPath).mkdir();
    Enumeration zipFileEntries = zip.entries();

    //Iterate overall zip file entries
    while (zipFileEntries.hasMoreElements())
    {
        ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) zipFileEntries.nextElement();
        String currentEntry = entry.getName();
        File destFile = new File(newPath, currentEntry);
        File destinationParent = destFile.getParentFile();
        //If entry is directory create sub directory on file system
        destinationParent.mkdirs();

        if (!entry.isDirectory())
        {
            //Copy over data into destination file
            BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(zip
            .getInputStream(entry));
            int currentByte;
            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
            //orthodox way of copying file data using streams
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
            BufferedOutputStream dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER);
            while ((currentByte = is.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                dest.write(data, 0, currentByte);
            }
            dest.flush();
            dest.close();
            is.close();
        }
    }
    return true;//some error codes etc.
}
```

The routine does not perform any exception handling, please catch the ZipException and IOException inside driver code.

Comment: when my friend unzip in iOS this zip can create all the folder,sub-folder and file in subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

My app contains Kotlin version of A.B.'s answer  fixing a Zip Path Traversal Vulnerability.

About the fix a Zip Path Traversal Vulnerability (from the website https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9294009 ):

"Zip files can contain an entry (file or directory) having path traversal characters (“../”) in its name. If developers unzip such zip file entries without validating their name, it can potentially cause a path traversal attack, leading to writes in arbitrary directories or even overwriting the files in the app's private folders.

We recommend fixing this issue in your app by checking if canonical paths to unzipped files are underneath an expected directory. Specifically, before using a File object created using the return value of ZipEntry's getName() method, always check if the return value of File.GetCanonicalPath() belongs to the intended directory path."

```
     /**
     * unzip file with subdirectories.
     *
     * Refer to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43672241/how-to-unzip-file-with-sub-directories-in-android)
     * answer of [A.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4914757/a-b)
     * Refer to [support.google.com](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9294009)
     * Refer to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303842/fixing-a-zip-path-traversal-vulnerability-in-android)
     * answer of [Indra Kumar S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3577946/indra-kumar-s)
     *
     * @param destination file
     * @param zipFile file
     * @return boolean
     */
    @Throws(ZipException::class, IOException::class)
    private fun extractFolder(destination: File, zipFile: File): Boolean {
        val BUFFER = 8192
        //      File file = zipFile;
        //This can throw ZipException if file is not valid zip archive
        val zip = ZipFile(zipFile)
        //      String newPath = destination.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + FilenameUtils.removeExtension(zipFile.getName());
        val newPath = destination.absolutePath + File.separator + stripExtension(
            zipFile.name.substring(zipFile.name.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
        )
        //Create destination directory
        File(newPath).mkdir()
        val zipFileEntries: Enumeration<*> = zip.entries()

        //Iterate overall zip file entries
        while (zipFileEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
            val entry = zipFileEntries.nextElement() as ZipEntry
            val currentEntry = entry.name
            val destFile = File(destination.absolutePath, currentEntry)
            //
            // String canonicalPath = destFile.getCanonicalPath();
            try {
                ensureZipPathSafety(destFile, destination)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // SecurityException
                e.printStackTrace()
                return false
            }
            //            if (!canonicalPath.startsWith(destination.getAbsolutePath())) {
            // SecurityException
//            }
            // Finish unzipping…
            //
            val destinationParent = destFile.parentFile
            //If entry is directory create sub directory on file system
            destinationParent!!.mkdirs()
            if (!entry.isDirectory) {
                //Copy over data into destination file
                val `is` = BufferedInputStream(
                    zip
                        .getInputStream(entry)
                )
                var currentByte: Int
                val data = ByteArray(BUFFER)
                //orthodox way of copying file data using streams
                val fos = FileOutputStream(destFile)
                val dest = BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER)
                while (`is`.read(data, 0, BUFFER).also { currentByte = it } != -1) {
                    dest.write(data, 0, currentByte)
                }
                dest.flush()
                dest.close()
                `is`.close()
            }
        }
        return true //some error codes etc.
    }

    /**
     * ensure Zip Path Safety.
     *
     *
     * Refer to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303842/fixing-a-zip-path-traversal-vulnerability-in-android)
     * answer of [Indra Kumar S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3577946/indra-kumar-s)
     *
     * @param destFile file
     * @param destination directory
     */
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    private fun ensureZipPathSafety(destFile: File, destination: File) {
        val destDirCanonicalPath = destination.canonicalPath
        val destFileCanonicalPath = destFile.canonicalPath
        if (!destFileCanonicalPath.startsWith(destDirCanonicalPath)) {
            throw Exception(
                String.format(
                    "Found Zip Path Traversal Vulnerability with %s",
                    destFileCanonicalPath
                )
            )
        }
    }
    /**
    * strip file name extension.
    *
    *
    * Refer to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541550/remove-the-extension-of-a-file)
    * answer of [palacsint](https://stackoverflow.com/users/843804/palacsint)
    *
    * @param s string file name
    * @return string file name without extension
    */
    fun stripExtension(s: String?): String {
            return if (s != null && s.lastIndexOf(".") > 0) s.substring(
                0,
                s.lastIndexOf(".")
            ) else s!!
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!