# Zip Path Traversal com.android.vending.expansion.downloader.R$string.decompress

Tags: android, android-studio, android-security, android-securityexception

I am using [this](https://github.com/googlearchive/play-apk-expansion/tree/master/apkx_library/src/com/google/android/vending/expansion/downloader) code to download expansion file. and I am getting alert "Zip Path Traversal" `"com.android.vending.expansion.downloader.R$string.decompress"`
Noting that I am not decompressing the downloaded file and in the code there is nothing called `decompress`.

Tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57734858/2828651) solution but no use.